# Action failed due to a Cognitive Services authentication error. Please check your authorization input and ensure it is correct

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-communication-services

I'm using Communication Service from Azure to make an outbound call following this example [Make an outbound call using Call Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/call-automation/quickstart-make-an-outbound-call?tabs=visual-studio-code&pivots=programming-language-csharp). This Communication Service is connected to an Azure Speech Service.

I'm receiving the call in my phone, but when I try to play the TextSource:

```
var GoodbyePlaySource = new TextSource(text)
{
    VoiceName = "es-ES-EstrellaNeural"
};

await callConnectionMedia.PlayToAllAsync(GoodbyePlaySource);
```

I receive the error

> Action failed due to a Cognitive Services authentication error. Please
> check your authorization input and ensure it is correct.

In the configuration of the call, I set the CognitiveServicesEndpoint:

```
CallInvite callInvite = new CallInvite(target, caller);
var createCallOptions = new CreateCallOptions(callInvite, callbackUri)
{
    CallIntelligenceOptions = new CallIntelligenceOptions() { CognitiveServicesEndpoint = new Uri(cognitiveServiceEndpoint) },
};
```

With the endpoint of my Speech Service:

```
 var cognitiveServiceEndpoint = "https://[REGION].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";
```

But I suppose that I've to add the KEY of the Speech Service somewhere to authenticate, but I can't see where is the place or maybe the error doesn't have to do with this?

Comment: Have you followed the steps in [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/call-automation/quickstart-make-an-outbound-call?tabs=visual-studio-code&pivots=programming-language-csharp#prerequisites) on how to connect your  [Multi-service Azure AI services to your Azure Communication Services resource.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/call-automation/azure-communication-services-azure-cognitive-services-integration).?

Comment: Yes, that's the point, the problem is that ACS doesn't works with a single Cognitive Services, it needs a Multi-service Azure AI, but you can connect a SpeechService, for example to ACS.

Comment: Create a multi-service resource for Azure AI [services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/multi-service-resource?tabs=windows&pivots=azportal)